# error: request for member which is of non-class type 'MULTIMEDIA_FILME [500]'|

Tags: c++

So the main objective of the program was to build a file and save on it the data I would input.

I did this with char and worked perfectly but I wanted to do with string too, so I tried the way I did with char and it gives me some errors

> error: request for member 'nome' in 'filmes', which is of non-class type 'MULTIMEDIA_FILME [500]'|

and the same for every string.

I tried deleting the [500] and the [1] in each string and it works, but I wanted to add and save various datas for the same strucure like:

```
Nome: "some name"
Tipo: "some type of movie"
Ano: "some year"
Descricao: "some description"
....
```

and repeat it once I do other input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME
{
string nome;
string tipo;
int ano;
string  descricao;
};

int main()
{
using namespace std;
struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME filmes [500] ;

fstream myFile("filme.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
ofstream filme_txt;
filme_txt.open("filme.txt");

cout << "Nome do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.nome[1];
filme_txt << filmes.nome[1] << endl;
cout << "Tipo do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.tipo[1];
filme_txt << filmes.tipo[1] << endl;
cout << "Ano do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.ano[1];
filme_txt << filmes.ano[1] << endl;
cout << "Descricao do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes.descricao[1];
filme_txt << filmes.descricao[1] << endl;

filme_txt.close();
}
```

EDIT1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME
{
string nome;
string tipo;
int ano;
string  descricao;
};

int main()
{
int n_filmes=0,contador,i=0;
struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME filmes [500] ;

FILE *ficheiro_num_filmes;
ficheiro_num_filmes=fopen("num_filmes.txt","rb");
if(ficheiro_num_filmes==NULL)
{
ficheiro_num_filmes=fopen("num_filmes.txt","wb");
fwrite(&n_filmes,sizeof(int),1,ficheiro_num_filmes);
fclose(ficheiro_num_filmes);
}
else
{
fread(&n_filmes,sizeof(int),1,ficheiro_num_filmes);
fclose(ficheiro_num_filmes);
}

fstream myFile("filme.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::ate | ios::app);
ofstream filme_txt;
filme_txt.open("filme.txt");

cout << "Quanto filmes deseja gravar:" << endl;
cin >> contador;
cout << "Nome do filme:" << filmes[1].nome << endl;
do{
cout << "Nome do filme:" << n_filmes+1 << endl;
cin >> filmes[1+n_filmes].nome;
filme_txt << filmes[1+n_filmes].nome << endl;
cout << "Tipo do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes[1+n_filmes].tipo;
filme_txt << filmes[1+n_filmes].tipo << endl;
cout << "Ano do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes[1+n_filmes].ano;
filme_txt << filmes[1+n_filmes].ano << endl;
cout << "Descricao do filme:" << endl;
cin >> filmes[1+n_filmes].descricao;
filme_txt << filmes[1+n_filmes].descricao << endl;
n_filmes ++;
i++;
}while(i<contador);

filme_txt.close();
ficheiro_num_filmes=fopen("num_filmes.txt","w+b");
fwrite(&n_filmes,sizeof(int),1,ficheiro_num_filmes);
fclose(ficheiro_num_filmes);




}
```

Comment: `struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME filmes [500] ;` in `c++` you don't need the `struct` part here just make it `MULTIMEDIA_FILME filmes[500] ;`

Comment: `cin >> filmes.nome[1];` => `cin >> filmes[1].nome;` also note that array indexing starts at `0` not with `1`.

Comment: Why do you have multiple `using namespace std;`s?

Comment: @drescherjm i changed it just for the counter file. not the main file where it stores the name os the movies etc

Comment: @drescherjm each time i open the program the other data that was inserted before gets deleted (and in my opinion it shouldnt happen since i openned with ios:app which i think it goes to the end of the file) the new code is edited on the main post.

Comment: This change does not seem to be related to the original question which was about a compiler error caused by improper array usage. Remember that at StackOverflow it is 1 question per question. Not solving all issues in your code. The reason for the 1 question limit is the to help users in the future with the same problem. This is the main goal of StackOverflow and one reason this site is not a forum.

Comment: Also the question is closed now. It is unlikely to be reopened. You may want to just ask a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has two problems:

1. The program declares 500 filmes objects.  This means that when you want to access the objects, the subscript should be provided prior to the member, e.g.

   ```
    filmes.nome[1]
   ```

   should be

   ```
    filmes[1].nome
   ```
2. There is no need to declare 500 objects.  Unless there is a requirement to create 500 different files, or to be able to store 500 different film objects, only one film object need be created.  So, a simplified version of the program would be:

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME {
        string nome;
        string tipo;
        int ano;
        string descricao;
    };

    int main() {
        struct MULTIMEDIA_FILME filmes;

        fstream myFile("filme.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
        ofstream filme_txt;
        filme_txt.open("filme.txt");

        cout << "Nome do filme:" << endl;
        cin >> filmes.nome;
        filme_txt << filmes.nome << endl;
        cout << "Tipo do filme:" << endl;
        cin >> filmes.tipo;
        filme_txt << filmes.tipo << endl;
        cout << "Ano do filme:" << endl;
        cin >> filmes.ano;
        filme_txt << filmes.ano << endl;
        cout << "Descricao do filme:" << endl;
        cin >> filmes.descricao;
        filme_txt << filmes.descricao << endl;

        filme_txt.close();
    }
   ```

If you truly wish to see 500 films stored in a single file, then you need to add some sort of while() loop to query up to 500 times for the film objects.  As your requirement did not request this, and as there is no loop in your program, I have not tried to debug this fork of the problem.

Here is updated code with a for loop in response to your comment.  Much more can be done.  The requirements are not clear as to when you want to overwrite the file(s) and when you want to append, and when you want to read back the contents of the file.  I suspect those are additional requirements that will come later.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Multimedia_Filme {
    string nome;
    string tipo;
    int ano;
    string descricao;
};

int GetFilmCountFromFile(const string &fileName) {
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(fileName);

    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        string line;
        getline(myFile, line);
        return stoi(line);  // convert string to int

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void WriteFileCountToFile(const string &fileName, int fileCount) {
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open(fileName);
    if(myFile.is_open()) {

        myFile << fileCount << endl;
        myFile.close();
    }

}

int GetIntFromUser(string prompt) {
    int count;
    cout << prompt << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> count;
    return count;
}

string GetStringFromUser(string prompt) {
    string returnString;
    cout << prompt << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1);
    cin >> returnString;
    return returnString;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n_filmes = 0, contador, i = 0;
    Multimedia_Filme filmes[500];

    n_filmes = GetFilmCountFromFile("filmCountFile.txt");
    contador = GetIntFromUser("Quanto filmes deseja gravar: ");


    ofstream filmeFile;
    filmeFile.open("filme.txt");
    if(filmeFile.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
            filmes[i].nome = GetStringFromUser("Nome do filme: ");
            filmes[i].tipo = GetStringFromUser("Tipo do filme: ");
            filmes[i].ano = GetIntFromUser("Ano do filme: ");
            filmes[i].descricao = GetStringFromUser("Descricao do filme: ");

            filmeFile << filmes[i].nome << endl
                   << filmes[i].tipo << endl
                   << filmes[i].ano << endl
                   << filmes[i].descricao << endl;
        }

        filmeFile.close();
    }

    WriteFileCountToFile("num_filmes.txt", contador);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, so i did a loop to insert the amount of movies i wanted, but now i have a problem. each time i open the program the other data that was inserted before gets deleted (and in my opinion it shouldnt happen since i openned with ios:app which i think it goes to the end of the file) the new code is edited on the main post.

Comment: It is kind of hard to follow the logic without breaking it down into functions.  As you get more experienced, you will find that std::cin is rarely used.  It is quirky.  Also, because you do not have an error processing, there are many corner cases that will not work.  E.g., you have to provide numerical input for the year, but not for the other fields.  I have updated my answer to give you a direction as to where I would take this.  This may be too advanced for the class you are working on.  If so, try to pull out the changes.